# Querying from SQL Server datetime conditions

Tags: sql-server

I have a `datetime` stored in SQL Server like '2021-10-12 18:46:31.047' and '2021-10-225 23:54:08.667' in one row..

How can I query from datetime by using date only not hours

```
WHERE str_day = '2021-10-23' AND end_day = '2021-10-24'
```

Help please

Comment: Please edit your question to add sample data and desired results in text format and add a tag for which version of SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns `str_day` and `end_day` are of time `DATETIME` (or `DATETIME2(n)`), then you can use something like this:

```
WHERE CAST(str_day AS DATE) = '2021-10-23' 
  AND CAST(end_day AS DATE) = '2021-10-24'
```

`DATE` is the date-only (no time portion) datatype - if your time portion is never needed, it might be useful to store those things as `DATE` from the beginning...

Comment: Recommended reading: [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea)

Answer (score 3):

Use date boundaries:

```sql
WHERE str_day >= '20211023'
  AND str_day < '20211024'
  AND end_day >= '20211024'
  AND end_day < '20211025'
```

Comment: i have 160 rows when i use this it return only 106 row

Comment: Then there are only 106 rows that meet the criteria, @hamedalgazaly .

Answer (score -2):

Use this; this will work for many scenario and types

```
WHERE str_day = '23 OCT 2021' 
  AND end_day = '24 OCT 2021'
```

Comment: This is *not* going to work. Firstly, the `datetime` value `2021-10-23T18:46:31.047` and the **`varchar`** value `'23 OCT 2021'` are *never* going to match; as the value would be converted to `2021-10-23T00:00:00.000` if it can be implicitly converted. Which brings us onto point 2, the above is language specific; if you weren't using an English based language, the above may well just error.